# Using wp_check_password with users stored in a custom table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, session

I am a seasoned PHP programmer, but new to WordPress. I am working on a project that integrates custom database tables with WordPress to create a simple but custom project management system. I would be **done** with this project already if I were working in straight PHP, but I see the wisdom in leveraging WordPress and definitely need to get through the pain on this first project!

SETUP: I am using WordPress 3.8.1 with up to date Gravity Forms plugin. I have a 'create new user' page where users are created. Using the Gravity Forms `after_submission` function to push these values into a custom table called `Finish_line_users`. Then a login page which registers the user and password in session variables. I have created a custom page template that then gathers the session variables and uses `wp_check_password` to verify the user is valid. I have done significant troubleshooting already and confirmed the following

1. session variables are storing properly.
2. users are getting input to the proper tables with the proper values
3. the actual `$hash` values match if you take the straight hash from the original create new user session and compare to the hash in the database.

Code at pastebin http://pastebin.com/Ay8rZKj0

The issue lies somewhere with my use of `wp_hash_password` and `wp_check_password`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so]. Questions should be self-contained, please post your code here (I've removed the part about a pastebin because there was no valid link).

Comment: Hi brasofilo. Sorry, on the road now and cant paste code here. Appreciate that questions should be self contained. Will do in future. I added valid pastebin link.